# Remove Date Grouping from Data

Tags: python, excel, group-by, pandas-groupby, data-cleaning

Looking to clean multiple data sets in a more automated way. The current format is year as column, month as row, the number values.

Below is an example of the current format, the original data has multiple years/months.

**Current Format:**

| Year | Jan | Feb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 300 | 200 |

Below is an example of how I would like the new format to look like. It combines month and year into one column and transposes the number into another column.

How would I go about doing this in excel or python? Have files with many years and multiple months.

**New Format:**

| Date | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | 300 |
| 2022-02 | 200 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below solution. You need to extend **month_df** for the months, current just cater to the example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2022],'Jan':[300],'Feb':[200]})

month_df = pd.DataFrame({'Char_Month':['Jan','Feb'], 'Int_Month':['01','02']})

melted_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Year'], value_vars=['Jan', 'Feb'], var_name='Char_Month',value_name='Number')

pd.merge(melted_df, month_df,left_on='Char_Month', right_on='Char_Month').\
assign(Year=melted_df['Year'].astype('str')+'-'+month_df['Int_Month'])\
[['Year','Number']]
```

Output:

[image]